# Simpilify sentence to avoid passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> The article 'a' and 'an' could only be used before singular nouns.

Is there a way to express the above sentence in a neater way? I mean without the `passive voice`.

e.g Is the following sentence valid:

> The article 'a' and 'an' uses only before singular nouns.

Comment: It is strictly a matter of opinion that "avoiding the passive" makes for a "neater" way to say something.  Furthermore, it's not a particularly well-informed opinion, either: [please read this about the passive](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) by linguist Geoffery Pullum.

Comment: @tchrist In the example from question, it's clear that the passive voice is neater, I am just talking about my example, not everything, don't think it so general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *The definite article (a or an) only [applies](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apply) to singular nouns*. This uses the second definition of *apply*

> Be applicable or relevant:

However, in this case, my opinion is that the passive voice is the clearest way of expressing the use of the definite article.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is not grammatical.  The verb 'uses' is not bidirectional.  I use a car; the car does not use me.

Generally, when changing from passive voice to active voice, you need to invert the sentence.

> Singular nouns are the only nouns that use the articles 'a' and 'an'

Comment: Hi, John. I think the active voice sentence should be "You could only use the article 'a' and 'an' before singular nouns as "by you/people" are omitted in the passive voice sentence. .

Comment: Ok, but still I want to know whether the 2nd sentence from question is valid?

Comment: I wanted to keep 3rd person...

Comment: @JohnFeltz But, I remember there is a thing called `Personification` in languages, is that valid in English?

Comment: This isn't quite right because the passive voice has writers or speakers as the (unspoken) agents.  Inverting to the active is awkward.  Singular nouns don't use articles; articles modify nouns. If you want *nouns* as a subject In the active voice, the idiom is that nouns take articles.

Comment: @deadrat I feel this passive voice wield too.

Comment: @EricWang What does "wield too" mean?

Comment: @deadrat I mean I feel the answer wield too

Comment: @EricWang *Wield* means to use a weapon, so I don't know what you mean. An answer can't wield anything.

Comment: @deadrat Ok, it's a typo, I mean `weird`.